# Can't convert string into float/double

Tags: c++

I'm writing a code for class where I take in input from a huge file (~850 lines) of data separated by commas.  what I have so far is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Station
{
string StationID, StationName;
float Elevation;
double Latitude, Longitude;
int Date, MXPN, MaxTemp, MinTemp, ObsTime;
};

int main ()
{
vector <string> Data;
string DummyLine, TempLine;
int Size = 0;

ifstream InputFile;
InputFile.open("finalc++.csv");
getline(InputFile, DummyLine);
while (InputFile.good())
    {
        getline(InputFile, TempLine);
        Size++;
        stringstream ss (TempLine);
        while (getline(ss, DummyLine, ',')) {
           Data.push_back(DummyLine);
        }

    }
Station Entry[Size];
for (int i = 0; i <= Size; i++)
    {
        Entry[i].StationID = Data[i * 10];
        Entry[i].StationName = Data[((i*10) + 1)];
        Entry[i].Elevation = Data[((i*10) + 2)];
        Entry[i].Latitude = Data[((i*10) + 3)];
        Entry[i].Longitude = Data[((i*10) + 4)];
        Entry[i].Date = Data[((i*10) + 5)];
        Entry[i].MXPN = Data[((i*10) + 6)];
        Entry[i].MaxTemp = Data[((i*10) + 7)];
        Entry[i].MinTemp = Data[((i*10) + 8)];
        Entry[i].ObsTime = Data[((i*10) + 9)];
    }


return 0;
}
```

I tried using `stof` to do this but could not get it anywhere near working.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert string to float by extracting float from string stream. At present you are using string stream but you are extracting string from it instead of float.

Try something like this:

```
stringstream ss;
while ( getline( InputFile, DummyLine, ',' ) )
{
  ss << DummyLine;
}
float dummyFloat;
while ( ss >> dummyFloat )
{
  Data.push_back( dummyFloat );
}
```

Comment: The thing is not all the data in the file is float.  some are strings, some doubles, some floats, and some int.  A line looks like this: GHCND:USC00083909,HIALEAH FL US,3.7,25.8175,-80.2858,20130101,250,239,200,800

Comment: also I didn't know you could add a float to a string vector.  Does this allow the entry to retain it's float type?

Answer (score 0):

Tray this:

```
//this can be cause exeptions
Entry[i].Elevation = atof (Data[((i*10) + 2)].c_str());
```

NOTE: include cstdlib

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Apparantly I need to update my compiler or some jazz.  Still trying to figure out how to do it.  I tried following http://nuwen.net/mingw.html but I still get the same error so idk what to do.